# Rendering video with custom data provided by user

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-scripting, rendering

I want to create a website where the user could input some data like texts, images, and based on that the video that contains that data will be rendered and downloaded.

Is there any services that could generate such a video based on project created on, for example After Effect, which will be display some user data in that film. The service must communicate via http in order to receive the data that will be presented on that video?

I thought about the rendering farms and After Effect scripts but I don't know if I will be able to do this using these tools?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The most sensible thing to do would be to host the service on your own. If you want users to input text, images and maybe even videos, you need a storage-unit which writes and reads these files incredibly quickly. An SSD-based server with a raid security would be appropriate. For the rendering: You could set up a standard After-Effects or Nuke Project. For After-Effects, you would need to do a lot of scripting to change the individual elements from your comp, but for Nuke, it should be easier, since Nuke is entirely in python and deals well with custom python-scripts. You'd then have to automate upon request that, first off, the Nuke-Script gets duplicated for the running instance, then replace the contents (text, images, etc.) accordingly, and render out. For rendering, I would recommend a GPU or CPU-based rendering-cluster with as many gpus or cpus as you need.

There probably are services that kind of do something similar, but they are either crazy expensive and not adjustable, or deviate from what you want to do.
Just don't expect this ordeal to be cheap and you won't run into bad surprises.

Answer (score 0):

[Templater Rig](https://aescripts.com/templater/) can link text and files from Google Sheets and CSV files into After Effects comps.  So if you can build your web service to feed data into one of these formats, you can get Templater and [After Effects render engine](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/user-guide.html/after-effects/using/automated-rendering-network-rendering.ug.html) combined to create video files.  Whether they will look any good is a significant question, as the layout of a good video is dependent on the length of text and content of images in the motion graphic.